# Is there a jquery method or other solution that can only detect changes in immediate child nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, browser

I found jquery method(`DOMSubtreeModified`) that detects the insert of child nodes of a specific dom.
However, this method detects the insertion of all child nodes, not just the immediate children.
Is there a jquery method or other solution that can only detect changes in immediate child nodes?

for example, in this situation:

```
<div id="content">
</div>
```

I only want to detect the following situation:

```
<div id="content">
   <div>one</div>
</div>
```

not this situation:

```
<div id="content">
   <div>one <span>add</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DOMSubtreeModified` is not specific to jQuery, it comes from Web APIs and [is now deprecated in favor of the Mutation Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Events/DOMSubtreeModified) .

To watch for changes in immediate children, use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) with `childList` set to `true`:

```js
const content = document.getElementById("content");

new MutationObserver(() => {
  console.log('[MutationObserver] Changes in immediate children detected');
}).observe(content, { childList: true });

setTimeout(() => {
  content.innerHTML += '<pre style="background: #7FDBFF;">There\'s a change in the DOM!</pre>';
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="content">
  Wait for it...
</div>
```

Apart from [`childList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit/childList) parameter, you can pass [`subtree: true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit/subtree) to detect changes to nested children too.

Answer (score 2):

Use MutationObserver with `childList: true`, which will detect changes to immediate children, but not to nested children:

```js
new MutationObserver(() => {
  console.log('mutation detected');
}).observe(content, { childList: true });

setTimeout(() => {
  content.innerHTML += '<div>one </div>';
}, 500);

setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#content > div').innerHTML += '<span>add</span>';
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
```

To detect changes to nested children too, you'd have to use `{ subtree: true }`:

```js
new MutationObserver(() => {
  console.log('mutation detected');
}).observe(content, { childList: true, subtree: true });

setTimeout(() => {
  content.innerHTML += '<div>one </div>';
}, 500);

setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#content > div').innerHTML += '<span>add</span>';
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Keep in mind that MutationObserver callbacks fire as a *microtask* (like `Promise.resolve().then`), unlike `DOMSubtreeModified`, which is completely synchronous.